# vb.net console app using sender As Object and e As EventArgs

Tags: vb.net, object, console-application, eventargs

I have the following code that allows my console app to go to the tray with an icon:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim tray As New NotifyIcon()

    tray.Icon = My.Resources.phoneIcon
    tray.Text = "Left Click to show console window"
    tray.Visible = True
    AddHandler tray.Click, AddressOf iconClicked

    ShowWindow(int, False)
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run()
End Sub

Private Sub iconClicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    if mouseLeft then
       ShowWindow(int, True)
    else
       ShowWindow(int, False)
    end if
End Sub
```

It also allows the console to be brought back up when left-clicking on the tray icon. The problem is, I need to be able to right-click to take it back down.

How can I use the ByVal e As EventArgs or ByVal sender As Object to detect which mouse button is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is change the line of the `Sub iconClicked` to use MouseEventArgs and not EventArgs; like so:

```
Private Sub iconClicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
```

One you have done that, you can use `e.Button` to figure out which button the user pressed.